# Convention de Stage in English

Tags: visa, france, internship

I've got an internship offer from a French company for 6 months and the working language will be English instead of french.

I've learnt that I need to apply for a visa and for that I need a "convention de stage" that needs to be approved by the DIRECCTE.

The company said that it's up to my school to provide the internship agreement. My school provided an Erasmus traineeship agreement which is in English and all parties have signed.

I would like to know if that agreement (in English) can be submitted to the DIRECCTE for approval or it has to be translated into French before.

PS: I'm from Togo(West Africa) but currently studying in Estonia

Comment: Which country are you a citizen of?  Erasmus is usually for EU+EEA+Switzerland, and citizens of those countries don't need a visa to take up an internship in France.

Comment: Your host institution (the French company) would normally the one issuing a convention de stage. So it's a bit weird that they told you otherwise.

Comment: Also, since the French immigration system would be analysing it, it would almost certainly need to be in French. Reach out to the Erasmus people, they must have seen this before.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique I also thought it should be the company issuing it but looks like it has to come from my university. I decided to translate it into French myself and take it to the university to sign. Hopefully they will agree to do that. so fingers crossed!

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm from Togo(west africa). Erasmus is not exclusively for EU citizens. Any student studying in an EU country can take part in the program

Comment: @HippolyteFayol Please [edit] your question to include that information (particularly the bit about you being from Togo).  (Irrelevant aside: I'm a native English speaker, and I wouldn't have guessed from your text that you aren't - whereas in fact it is presumably your *third* language.)

Comment: A bit late, found a template : http://travail-emploi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/convention_stage_tripartite.pdf

Comment: When you do a _stage_ in France as a part of an educational cursus, it is usually (if not always) the educational body that edits the _convention de stage_ and submits it to the company involved. That is why the company is expecting your university to provide it.